# ISN AutoIT Studio - creating new form

Tags: user-interface, autoit

I created .isf form file in ISN studio. In my main.au3 file I have included this form (#include "Forms\main.isf"). But when i hit run nothing happens. Do I have to add somenthing in my main.au3? (I'm pretty new with AutoIT)

Also when I look into code which form generates there is:

```
$btn1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Button",170,70,100,30,-1,-1)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1,"onBtn1Click")
```

shloudn't be there $btn1 instead of -1 in the second line?

Thanks :)

Comment: "-1" denotes the last GUI control that has been created in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it a user defined function (UDF). That won't work because a UDF needs to be a `.au3` file. I'm not familiar with ISN studio, however to include a UDF you need to do this.

```
#include "C:\path\myfunctions.au3"
```

Also if the UDF is in the same location as the script you can just use the relative path like this.

```
#include "myfunctions.au3"
```

Here is are some example UDF's.

http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/User_Defined_Functions

Comment: See if there is an export or a way to save as au3. Typically you want to use one script for the GUI. then you can use other UDFs as additional code if you need it. you can also put the functions in the same script. So yes it can be all one big file

Answer (score 1):

You have done nothing wrong; just forgot something.

It's correct to include the `.isf` file in your script. So the GUI is already present, just hidden! You only need to show it using: [`GuiSetState(@SW_SHOW, $HANDLE_OF_YOUR_GUI)`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUISetState.htm).

Then you should see your GUI! As an example see the "Testproject" in ISN AutoIt Studio.